# Report based on a Document Library with Document Sets

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I'm currently trying to create a report/list/webpart based on a document library with only document sets.

The main purpose is to show if a document set contains (or not) all its "allowed content types".

Example (doesn't need to be exactly like this):

[image]

[image]

Is there anyway to create this list/report out-of-box? Or only with custom code (Javascript and REST API, maybe)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Although disabled through the UI since SP2010 you can still Group By ContentType.

Full explanation at: http://joelblogs.co.uk/2011/10/29/restoring-group-by-content-type-to-sharepoint-2010-list-views/

There are 2 Methods described;

Joel uses a Feature, I prefer adding the code to EditView.aspx page with TamperMonkey/GreaseMonkey (no equivalent for IE), that way I do not have to add or change anything IN SharePoint.
By naming my view xxxx_gtp.aspx Tampermonkey triggers on the correct page;
and can fix the issue of resetting Joel describes.

Joels code:

```
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("jbCTFix");

    function jbCTFix() {
        jbCTKludge('idGroupField1');
        jbCTKludge('idGroupField2');
    }
    function jbCTKludge(selName) {
        var sel = document.getElementById(selName);
        if (sel) {
            if (sel.selectedIndex >= 0) {

                var o = document.createElement('option');
                o.text = 'Content Type';
                o.value = 'tp_ContentType';

                var prev = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
                try {
                    sel.add(o, prev);
                }
                catch (ex) {
                    sel.add(o, sel.selectedIndex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. With this I solve one of the problems, but I can't display all the documents (content types) that aren't available inside the document set. I need to show all the documents (content types) that are and aren't inside their document set.